# How do I control the playback of multiple Youtube Videos with the Youtube JS api?

Tags: javascript, youtube, slider, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Here's the problem:
I have multiple youtube videos in a slider, and I want the videos to stop playing when a link that controls the slider is clicked. It's really annoying to have the videos just keep playing when you can't see it.

I used this code:

```
<div id="ytapiplayer2">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {ytplayer2 = document.getElementById("myvideo");}
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };var atts = { id: "myvideo" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/hCarSDT7cSQ?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=myvideo","ytapiplayer2", "425", "270", "8", null, null, params, atts);
    function play() {if (ytplayer2) {ytplayer2.playVideo();}}
    function pause() {if (ytplayer2) {ytplayer2.pauseVideo();}}
</script>
```

Which is basically directly from Google's Youtube js api stuff.[1](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) It works GREAT for just ONE video, per page.

My problem is I have some pages where I want to have multiple videos in the same slider. Videos are contained within divs, and called exactly as shown above in each respective div.

BUT -- The videos don't stop playing back now when navigating links for the slider are clicked. :(

I have tried to change the variable and id names to be unique each time the script is called. I have even changed the function name from function onYouTubePlayerReady to onYouTubePlayerReady2 ... but nothing works.

I'm stumped. Halp?

---

Edit to show more detailed code set up:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--Uses Google API library-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--Uses Google API library-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodyContent">
    <div id="leftCol">
        Content
    </div><!-- #leftCol -->
        <div id="middleCol">
        <ul id="subNav">
                 <li class="category">Mini Header</li>
                 <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul><!--subNav-->
                </div><!-- #middleCol -->
                <div id="rightCol" class="slider">
                    <div class="scroll">
                        <div class="scrollContainer">                  
                            <div id="link1" class="panel">
                            <div id="ytapiplayer1">
                                You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
                                </div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {ytplayer1 = document.getElementById("myVideo1");}
                                var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };var atts = { id: "myVideo1" };
                                swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/67aIIRv-dYU?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer1","ytapiplayer1", "425", "347", "8", null, null, params, atts);
                                function play() {if (ytplayer1) {ytplayer1.playVideo();}}
                                function pause() {if (ytplayer1) {ytplayer1.pauseVideo();}}
                                </script>
                            </div><!-- #link1 -->
                            <div id="link2" class="panel">
                            <div id="ytapiplayer2">
                                You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
                                </div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {ytplayer2 = document.getElementById("myVideo2");}
                                var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };var atts = { id: "myVideo2" };
                                swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/67aIIRv-dYU?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer1","ytapiplayer2", "425", "347", "8", null, null, params, atts);
                                function play() {if (ytplayer2) {ytplayer2.playVideo();}}
                                function pause() {if (ytplayer2) {ytplayer2.pauseVideo();}}
                                </script>
                            </div><!-- #link2 -->
                    <div>Video 3 set up is same as above...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- .scroll -->
                </div><!-- #rightCol -->
</div><!-- #bodyContent -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong approach. Why use *two or more* YouTube players when you can accomplish the task with *one* player, specially when you're using YouTube JS API.

Relevant code:

```
<div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="load('hCarSDT7cSQ'); return false;">Video 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="load('67aIIRv-dYU'); return false;">Video 2</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function load(id) {
    if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.loadVideoById(id);
    }
}
</script>
```

## [Demo for solution 1](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/twfXb/)

Alternately you can create multiple players and figure out some way of storing how many players you have on the page in a variable. I think it is sufficient to store the `id` of the player. Do not confuse the `id` with (i) the id you assign to the div (ii) the id you pass as `playerapiid`.

`swfobject.embedSWF()` will replace the div with either an `object` or `embed` tag, that tag is assigned an id that you pass to this method in the last parameter. This is the id that you can later use to reference the player(s).

## [Demo for solution 2](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/dYUB8/)

Comment: I really appreciate the code you gave above (it works!) and I will definitely use your approach in the future. *However*, for this current project I *do* need to have two youtube players because the videos are to appear in **different parts of the jquery slider**. By this point in the website, there is already an expectation built on the previous site navigation that there be a slide effect between project elements (project elements = content of the slider). Any possible way to have two video players that you know of? Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, the code doesn't work with sliders. I added other content (besides videos) back into the slider and only the first video plays now.

Comment: @lzheidi: it is difficult to manage more than one player, specially when you try to attach event handlers to the players. Having said that, it is possible. I'll update the fiddle in few minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really struggling with this one.

Comment: Thank you so much Salman A!! I finally had a chance to try this and it works great! For those curious about stopping the videos, I used **Solution 2**, and added to the bottom of the code: 'function paws1(){paws('yt_player_1'); return false;}
function paws2(){paws('yt_player_2'); return false;}' 
and so on for each player on the page. In the 'a href' links for my slider nav, I put 'onclick="paws1();paws2();"' etc depending on how many vids I needed to embed in that page.

Awesome awesome solution, extremely helpful. Thanks again Salman!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>                
    var player1st;
    var player2nd;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
    player1st = new YT.Player('frame1st', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}}); 
    player2nd = new YT.Player('frame2nd', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}});
        }              
    //function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player2nd = new YT.Player('frame2nd', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}}); }                
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    alert(event.target.getPlayerState());        
    }        
</script>                        
<iframe id="frame1st" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1g30Xyh6Wqc?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.playVideo(); return false">play1st</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.pauseVideo(); return false">pause1st</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.stopVideo(); return false">stop1st</a>                
<iframe id="frame2nd" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T39hYJAwR40?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe><br>    
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.playVideo(); return false">play2nd</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.pauseVideo(); return false">pause2nd</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.stopVideo(); return false">stop2nd</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the references to each player in an array, then when you want to stop them all loop through the array. If you could post more of your HTML/JavaScript for the multiple video setup I might have a more specific suggestion, otherwise fill in the blanks yourself:

```
// add a global array of video refs
var myVideos = [];

// some code to create the first video, similar to OP code
// ...
myVideos.push(ytplayer2);

// some code to create second video
// ...
myVideos.push(anotherVideoRef);

// some code to create third video
// ...
myVideos.push(thirdVideoRef);

// etc.

function pauseAllVideos(){
   for (var i = 0; i < myVideos.length; i++) {
      myVideos[i].pauseVideo();
   }
}
```

I would prefer to setup the videos in a loop, rather than one at a time like I did above, but I don't know how the rest of your code is structured, so...

Comment: I'm not sure how to do what you are suggesting. I will update my original post to show a more detailed view of how the code is set up. Only the jquery to make the slider work is missing. The video js is really as simple as what I've shown...